# Save a float value into a char(15) variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, char

How can I save the value of `float` variable `NumFiscalActual` into the `char(15)` column `impfisfac`

On sql server...

```
UPDATE FACTURA SET
impfisfac= cast(@NumFiscalActual AS varchar)
```

I know I've to use `char variable='char value'`, but with this cast function... I dunno =/

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: float is upto 15 significant figures. For very small and very large number, varchar(15) will lose data.

- `0.0000123456789012345` is >15 length
- 1.23456789012345E-05 is >15 length

You could try this

```
UPDATE FACTURA SET impfisfac= cast(@NumFiscalActual AS varchar(15)) WHERE...
```

(You need the WHERE clause otherwise every row will get the value)

However, there are issues converting floats: you may find that decimal places are lost (I can't remember exact rules).

So, you can use [STR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx), for example

```
UPDATE FACTURA SET impfisfac= RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(@NumFiscalActual,38,16))) WHERE...
```

But you'll lose data as above. So why? Or use decimal fixed point types....